# quero fazer comparação no MySQL "IF" ou "CASE"

Tags: mysql

Eu só quero fazer uma comparação de datas no MySQL porém não consigo. Me ajudem, é para ver se a data e maior ou igual a uma data, e menor igual a outra data.

```
SELECT
    (CASE 
        WHEN '2019/12/05 00:00:00' >= age_start THEN 'existe' 
        WHEN '2019/12/05 00:00:00'<= age_end 
        ELSE 'okay' 
    END)
FROM agenda
```

Após pesquisar cheguei a esse código porém não esta certo, porquê?

Comment: Não seria mais simples algo do tipo: 
`SELECT * FROM agenda WSHERE  age_start <= '2019/12/05 00:00:00' AND age_end >= '2019/12/05 00:00:00';` ?

Answer (score 1):

Você esqueceu de colocar o segundo `THEN`, e pulou direto para o `ELSE`:

```sql
SELECT
   (CASE WHEN '2019/12/05 00:00:00' >= age_start THEN 'existe' 
         WHEN '2019/12/05 00:00:00'<= age_end THEN 'Menor igual a age_end' -- <=== Faltou essa parte
         ELSE 'okay' END
   )FROM agenda
```

Mas se você simplesmente quer retornar "okay" se estiver dentro do período, deveria tentar assim:

```sql
SELECT
   (CASE WHEN '2019/12/05 00:00:00' BETWEEN age_start AND age_end THEN 'Okay' 
         ELSE 'Not okay' END
   )FROM agenda
```

Comment: No segundo caso, dá para usar [`IF(condition, true_value, false_value)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) também ;D